# Change status field options in edit user screen

Tags: hooks

I want to change the *status* field (`radio`) options from `Blocked/Active` to `Unapproved/approve` in Drupal 8.5. How to achieve it?

I have tried with `Hook_form_alter` and tried to change the options with `$form` parameter but no success.

This is the code I have tried:

```
  $form['status']['#options'] = [1 => t('Published'),0 =>t('Not Published') ];
```

Comment: Your installation is dangerously outdated - you should update to a modern version of Drupal 8 before you do anything else

Comment: No.. Its 8.5 version

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue...

Following is the code:

```
 $form['account']['status']['#title'] = 'User Status';
 $form['account']['status']['#options'] = [1 => t('Published'),0 =>t('Not Published') ];
```

I am missing the **account** parameter.